# Erro ao conectar no Entity Framework em um BD ja existente

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Criei um aplicação que utiliza o Entity Framework 6X e o modo Code First por Fluent API, fazendo o Map das Classes, utilizando classes do meu modelo , e criando a classe de contexto. Quando tento me conectar para verificar se pelo menos uma das minhas entidades retornam alguma informação e se ocorrerá a conexão com o banco corretamente , ele me da a mensagem de erro: "Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.InvalidOperationException" em EntityFramework.dll
The store type 'numeric(2, 0)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest". no debug na aplicação Console ele passa pela primeira linha de definição do db,e o erro ocorre logo ao tentar pegar um ToList() da entidade Impostos.

Segue abaixo a minha classe contexto, a string de conexão no BD do app.config, a minha classe de modelo, e o codigo chamado de teste na aplicação console.

Contexto :

```
namespace apiIntegracaoSFI.DAL.Modelo
{
   public class SFIContext : DbContext
    {
        public SFIContext() : base("SFIContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        }

        public DbSet<Imposto> Impostos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(p => p.Name == p.ReflectedType.Name + "Id")
                .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(100));

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ImpostoMap());

        }
    }
}
```

app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SFIContext"
         connectionString="data source=SQLNTE103;initial catalog=FATURAMENTO;user id=SFI;password=*********;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Classe de Mapeamento :

```
namespace apiIntegracaoSFI.DAL.DataAcess.Mapping
{
    public class ImpostoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Imposto>
    {
        public ImpostoMap()
        {

            this.ToTable("SAP_IMPOSTO");

            this.HasKey(e => new { e.CodigoSap, e.CategoriaImpostos });

            this.Property(e => e.CodigoSap)
                .HasColumnName("CODIGO_SAP")
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
                .HasMaxLength(10);


            this.Property(e => e.CategoriaImpostos)
                .HasColumnName("CATEGORIA_IMPOSTOS")
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
                .HasMaxLength(4);


            this.Property(e => e.ClassificacaoFiscal)
                .HasColumnName("CLASSIFICACAO_FISCAL")
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
                .HasMaxLength(1);


            this.Property(e => e.Pais)
                .HasColumnName("PAIS")
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
                .HasMaxLength(3);

        }
    }
}
```

Classe do Modelo :

```
namespace apiIntegracaoSFI.DAL.Modelo
{
    public class Imposto
    {
        public string CodigoSap { get; set; }
        public string CategoriaImpostos { get; set; }
        public string ClassificacaoFiscal { get; set; }
        public string Pais { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Codigo de Teste do Console:

```
namespace ConsoleTeste
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SFIContext db = new SFIContext();

            var impostos = db.Impostos.ToList();

            foreach (var imp in impostos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Codigo SAP: " + imp.CodigoSap);
                Console.WriteLine("Imposto: " + imp.CategoriaImpostos);
                Console.WriteLine("Classificacao: " + imp.ClassificacaoFiscal);
                Console.WriteLine("Pais: " + imp.Pais);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```